# creating a vb6 setup with mysql via inno setup

Tags: mysql, vb6, inno-setup

I have a VB6 project whose setup I have created using inno-setup creator since VB creator has become quite old.

I have been including some `.ocx` files already in the setup, so that the application runs in every PC:

```
;Adding .ocx files
Source: "Setup Creator\comctl32.ocx"; DestDir: "{sys}"; Flags: regserver onlyifdoesntexist uninsneveruninstall
Source: "Setup Creator\MSMASK32.OCX"; DestDir: "{sys}"; Flags: regserver onlyifdoesntexist uninsneveruninstall
Source: "Setup Creator\mscomct2.ocx"; DestDir: "{sys}"; Flags: regserver onlyifdoesntexist uninsneveruninstall
```

The software uses MySQL ODBC Connector v3.51. What files do I need to add to the setup script for this?

Comment: I'm a bit lost in your question. What does *"I need to ensure that the MySQL thing runs too"* mean ? What is the *"thing"* ? Or, is your question just how to install MySQL ODBC driver if it's not already installed and the rest of the question is unrelated ?

Comment: @TLama: I have edited the question. See, like in c#.net, we add a `.dll` from reference for running the application in PCs where MySql connector is not present. I want to do something on those lines in vb6 also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a hell lot of trying (sleepless nights included). I found my answer.

From the `C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector ODBC 3.51` directory. Copy the following files into your setup creator directory.

Then include the following lines in your setup script:

```
;Copy MySQL ODBC Dependencies to {sys}
Source: "Setup Creator\myodbc3.dll"; DestDir: "{sys}"; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist uninsneveruninstall
    Source: "Setup Creator\myodbc3.lib"; DestDir: "{sys}"; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist uninsneveruninstall
    Source: "Setup Creator\myodbc3i.exe"; DestDir: "{sys}"; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist uninsneveruninstall
    Source: "Setup Creator\myodbc3S.dll"; DestDir: "{sys}"; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist uninsneveruninstall
    Source: "Setup Creator\myodbc3S.lib"; DestDir: "{sys}"; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist uninsneveruninstall

[Run]
;Do this before cm:launchprogram
Filename: "{sys}\myodbc3i"; Parameters:"-a -d -t""MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver;DRIVER=myodbc3.dll;SETUP=myodbc3s.dll""";
```